# An intuitive idea of the arrow operator applicative

Tags: haskell

I had a couple of hours of fun today trying to understand what the arrow operator applicative does in Haskell. I am now trying to verify whether my understanding is correct. In short, I found that for the arrow operator applicative

```
 (f <*> g <*> h <*> v) z = f z (g z) (h z) (v z)
```

Before I proceed, I am aware of [this discussion](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/348233/how-is-arrow-operator-an-applicative-functor-in-haskell) but found it to be very convoluted and much more complicated than what I hope I derived today.

In order to understand what the applicative does I started from the definition of the arrow applicative in base

```
instance Applicative ((->) a) where
    pure = const
    (<*>) f g x = f x (g x)
```

and then proceeded to explore what the expressions

```
(f <*> g <*> h) z
```

and

```
(f <*> g <*> h <*> v) z
```

yield when expanded.

From the definition we get that

```
 f <*> g = \x -> f x (g x)
```

Because `(<*>)` is left associative, it follows that

```
 f <*> g <*> h = (f <*> g) <*> h
               = (\x -> f x (g x)) <*> h
               = \y -> (\x -> f x (g x)) y (h y)
```

Therefore

```
 (f <*> g <*> h) z = (\y -> (\x -> f x (g x)) y (h y)) z
                   = (\x -> f x (g x)) z (h z)
                   = (f z (g z)) (h z)
                   = f z (g z) (h z)
```

The last step is due to the fact that function application is left associative. Similarly

```
 (f <*> g <*> h <*> v) z = f z (g z) (h z) (v z)
```

This, to me, provides a very clear intuitive idea of what the arrow applicative does. **But is this correct?**

To test the result I ran, for example, the following,

```
λ> ((\z g h v -> [z, g, h, v]) <*> (1+) <*> (2+) <*> (3+)) 4
[4,5,6,7]
```

which conforms to the result derived above.

Before doing the expansion above I found this applicative very difficult to understand, since *extremely* complicated behaviour can result from its use because of currying. In particular, in

```
 (f <*> g <*> h <*> v) z = f z (g z) (h z) (v z)
```

functions can return other functions. Here is an example:

```
λ> ((\z g -> g) <*> pure (++) <*> pure "foo" <*> pure "bar") undefined
"foobar"
```

In this case `z=undefined` is ignored by all functions, because `pure x z = x` and the first function ignores `z` by construction. Furthermore, the first function takes only two arguments but returns a function taking two arguments.

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Comment: Your intuition is exactly right. Next, you should tackle the `Monad` instance. In studying the instances for `(->) r`, you can also gain valuable intuitions for other applicatives and monads.

Comment: Thanks guys! It's very mathematically rewarding to derive a result with pen and paper after noticing that an empirical approach to understanding fails miserably. And sure thing, monad instance next.

Comment: writing  this with redundant parentheses might make it clearer and easier to read, like `(f <*> g <*> h <*> v) z = (f z) (g z) (h z) (v z)`.  it is also `sequenceA [f,g,h,v] z = [f z, g z, h z, v z]`. in general, `instance Applicative ((->) x) where pure v x = v ; (f <*> g) x = (f x) $ (g x)` too can be easier to read.

Comment: Will, I like the symmetry in the form `(f z) (g z) (h z) (v z)`, but also like `f z (g z) (h z) (v z)` simply because it explicitly shows that there are four arguments supplied to `f.`

Comment: btw `(\z g -> g)` is just `pure id`. see? you thought about it in a special way, but it isn't special. It's an `id` supplied with *one* argument, `(++)`. :) I find it much [easier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45516443/849891) to think with [combinatory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic) equations, than with lambda definitions. `f = \x -> \y -> \z -> g` === `f x y z = g`, "what's the problem?"

Comment: your question is great as it shows that it is much easier to learn stuff when we put several/many related things side-by-side, like your `f<*>g<*>h` and `f<*>g<*>h<*>v`. Just one definition is usually given, for the `f<*>g`, which we need to "understand" then. But with multiple definitions, we can *see* the pattern. Human cognition is much tied up with our visual perception. This should be acknowledged and used more. Same with `sequenceA [f,g,h] z = [f z, g z, h z]`, which *looks* "the same" in a way, just "parens" are different. Multiple examples kind of "show" *why* a feature is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your calculations are correct.

Comment: I would add: `<*>` in the function applicative is the S combinator from combinatory logic: S *f* *g* *e* = *f* *e* (*g* *e*); it applies *f* to *g*, where each of them can access the “environment” *e*.